# Xamarin: Progress Bar Change Color

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, colors, xamarin, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Loading..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I need change default color (grey). I need change the color programatically or xml forms.

In my Activity I have:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoadingBar);
var progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. My example is if a value of seconds gets below 10 then the progress bar color changes to red.

```
if (seconds < 10) {
progressBar.ProgressDrawable.
SetColorFilter (Android.Graphics.Color.Red, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code change to expected color and center of screen

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorprimary"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/login_loading" />
```